# WPF page binding failing

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I was hoping someone would be kind enough to steer me in the right direction.
I’m trying to get my head around WPF.
I’ve created a 4.8 framework application with two buttons and a frame on the main window.  I’m using Caliburn.Micro for binding – This is my test application to try and understand it.
When you press the first button, the window context is set to a page, with an Employees data grid upon it.  The data is fed from a back end Oracle Database (I’m trying to follow the MVVM pattern.)   This works perfectly.
When you press the other button, the main window displays a second page within the frame – This time, Departments.  This much works.  I have a an unbound textbox in the page and this shows as it should.
The part I have spent two days trying to get to work is the data grid for the Departments.  It returns blank.

I know for certain that the Departments variable is being populated.  I have confirmed this two ways.  I have stepped through the code and can see values being populated.  I have also placed the code below in the Employee page and had the data grid display with values.
I have also tried to display the employees data grid within the Departments page but it too is blank at run time.
To the best of my ability to discern, the code behind the two pages is identical aside from the obvious name change.

This is from my Departments View Model:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using DataLibrary;

namespace WpfEmployees.ViewModels
{
    public class DepartmentsViewModel : Screen
{
        public BindableCollection<DepartmentsModel> Departments { get; set; }
        public DepartmentsViewModel()
        {
            DepartmentsProcessor dp = new DepartmentsProcessor();
            Departments = new BindableCollection<DepartmentsModel>(dp.LoadDepartments());
        }
    }
}
```

From the view:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Departments" ></DataGrid>
```

I'm not seeing any error messages, just a blank data grid.
Any suggestions of where I might look for my error would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I would [start with plain MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/), and then add Caliburn.micro if you ever encounter a problem that's solved more simply with Caliburn than with MVVM. MVVM and WPF by themselves are enough to contend with.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go.

Comment: I've got to working, thank you.  I populated the data grid in the xaml.cs file using itemssource and a passed in list from a method call to a method in the view model class.  I'm still hazy on where the various boundaries are that make up MVVM (hence my "playing") so I hope I haven't violated the patern by doing it this way.  I tried moving the datagrid population to the view model but I could get it to recognize the existence of the datagrid.  Please forgive me if this is a stupid idea.  I'm still trying to figure out which way is up on WPF.  Thank you again.

Comment: I can't guess what your code is doing, but the usual thing is: Create a viewmodel. Give it a property that's an `ObservableCollection<DepartmentsModel>` (or if it has properties that will be edited in the UI, then instead of `DepartmentsModel`, write a `DepartmentsViewModel` with INPC). Assign the viewmodel to the DataContext of the view (for the main view, just do this in the view's constructor). Use a Binding: `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}"`. The advantage is it's easy and simple and it always works. I don't know how Caliburn does things.

Comment: Thank you. I have finally got there using your suggested method.  Initially, I couldn't get it to work.  It took me a while to figure out how to set the datacontext at the class level.  I'd gone the Calliburn.Micro route in the first place because I was trying to understand binding. I'd to swap the pages I was using for userControls and the frame for one too (although, I've no idea if this swap out contributed to it working, as it wouldn't at the time but I couldn't figure out how to set the windows resource for a pages.)  I'd love to set this as answered to give you credit but cannot see how.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work:
Main window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfEmployees.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfEmployees"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:WpfEmployees.ViewModels"

    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WpfEmployees.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="850" Width="650" Loaded="ShowDepartmentsPage">
    <Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="employeesViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:EmployeesViewModel}">
        <views:EmployeesView DataContext="{Binding}"/>

    </DataTemplate

    <DataTemplate x:Name="departmentsViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:DepartmentsViewModel}">
        <views:DepartmentsView DataContext="{Binding}"/>

    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
...
            <Button x:Name="ShowEmployeesBtn" Content="Employees"
                    Margin="10 0 0 0" Click="ShowEmployeesPage"/>
            <Button x:Name="ShowDepartmentsBtn" Content="Departments"
                    Margin="10 0 0 0" Click="ShowDepartmentsPage" />
...
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Main window class button code**

```
public partial class MainWindow
    {
...

private void ShowEmployeesPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 DataContext = new EmployeesViewModel();
}
```

**View Model Code**

```
public class EmployeesViewModel 
...
public ObservableCollection<EmployeesModel> ObEmployees { get; set; }
...
public EmployeesViewModel()
        {
            EmployeesProcessor ep = new EmployeesProcessor();
            ObEmployees = new ObservableCollection<EmployeesModel>
(ep.LoadEmployees());
        }
```

I don't know if this is the best route. It works but I'm too new at WPF to know. I'm hoping this is what Ed Plunkett had in mind, so it may be.  Thank you again, Ed.